# Dynamics AX 2012 FactBoxes closed at start

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, morph-x

Is there a way to close FactBoxes at start, so that you have to open them manually each time?

Comment: please provide any attempts you've tried this far.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to [disable fact boxes for good](http://learnax.blogspot.dk/2012/02/enabledisable-fact-boxes-preview-panes.html)?